# Plotting coordinates in folium from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I am having trouble plotting coordinates from the values found in my data frame onto my folium map. All questions & answers I have searched on StackOverflow show people using the exact same process as me to achieve their results however mine produces an error.
Anybody have any ideas why I am receiving this error?
Below is my data frame, my code for plotting the points, and the unusual error.

**Dataframe**
[image: Data frame]

**Code**

```
for animal in animals:
    url = 'http://www.bloowatch.org{}'.format
    icon_image = url(animals['image'])
    icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(f"http://www.bloowatch.org{animals['image']}", icon_size=(30,30))
    
    
    
    folium.Marker(
        location = [animals['lat'], animals['lon']],
        icon = icon,
        popup=animals['population']
    ).add_to(m)
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: Location should consist of two numerical values, but 0     21.0
1     34.0
2     -6.0
3     21.0
4     -3.0
5     29.0
6     -3.0
7    -14.0
8    -18.0
9    -22.0
10    27.0
11    77.0
Name: lat, dtype: float64 of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> is not convertible to float.
```

As you can see, cannot convert float to float is baffling me.
Any ideas as to how to overcome this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Location Parameter only gets a list or tuple with two values,

> location (tuple or list, default None) – Latitude and Longitude of Map (Northing, Easting).

you're giving it a list of values. For example, to pass only two values

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
```